# Bradford Reagent Disposal

Tags: biochemistry

I am a graduate student volunteering in a professor's lab being tasked with finding out how to dispose of certain hazardous materials. I have encountered a problem with disposing of Bradford's Reagent. I have checked online, but am running into problems due to the methanol component of this compound. Can someone help me with the proper disposal procedure? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would strongly suggest to ask someone in your lab about this, they will have a better idea about the different waste disposal methods you have available.

In general you would dispose anything that contains organic solvents like methanol in a waste container for generic solvent waste. You should have something like that somewhere in the lab.

One thing you always have to keep in mind is to never put anything still reactive into your waste container. A popular example would be a strong oxidizing agent, putting that into a solvent waste container is dangerous and could e.g. ignite the waste. This is not an issue in this case, but you should always keep that in mind.

Another aspect is the pH of the waste, in many cases the waste disposal facility will only accept reasonably neutral waste, so you should neutralize your waste before putting it into a container. Neutralizing it inside the container can be much more annoying. This might not be necessary if you have a dedicated acidic waste, you'll have to ask someone in your lab about that. The Bradford reagent is strongly acidic, so you'll have to pay attention to this aspect.

Comment: @wingsfan1340 If this answer [addressed your problem](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking on the check mark/tick to the left of the answer, turning it green. This marks the question as resolved to your satisfaction, and awards [reputation](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) both to you and the person who answered.